# Entity Framework Group Sum handling empty values

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Im trying to return monthly sum from database table CustomerComplaintExpenseRows. Since I need monthly value even if it's 0 I have to group Range of months with sum query. In var q cc.sum might be null in some months and decimal datatype won't accept "?? 0" -operation. How can I get my code to return 0 if the value is empty?

```cs
var firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
var lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);

var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .Select(month => month)
            .ToList();

var complaints = _context.CustomerComplaintExpenseRows
                   .Where(a => a.CustomerComplaint.ComplaintDate > firstDayOfYear 
                            && a.CustomerComplaint.ComplaintDate < lastDayOfYear)
                   .GroupBy(o => o.CustomerComplaint.ComplaintDate.Month)
                   .Select(a => new
                   {
                       a.Key,
                       sum = a.Sum(i => i.RowValue)
                   })
                   .ToList();

var q = from m in months
        join cc in complaints on m equals cc.Key into joined
        from cc in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            name = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fi-FI")
                        .DateTimeFormat
                        .GetAbbreviatedMonthName(m),
            value = cc.sum
        };
```

Example results Im looking for:

```
[
    {
    "name": 'Jan',
    "value": 300,00
    },
    {
    "name": 'Feb',
    "value": 0,00
    },
    {
    "name": 'Mar',
    "value": 5,30
    },
]
```

Comment: which field is empty? looks really close to what it should be...

Comment: @Seabizkit Results from the first query (var complaints) only contains months with rows. For example if there are no results in January the query returns only 11 rows. Now when I call "value = cc.sum" for January cc will be null (System.NullReferenceException)

Comment: in that case you should be able to do `value = (cc.sum == null)? 0: cc.sum`

Comment: @Seabizkit It works seamlessly! Thanks for the help

Comment: you explained  what was wrong well!! so, i got the idea... been there many times. pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness

set value like this..

```
value = (cc.sum == null)? 0: cc.sum
```